# Autoscroll not stopping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script to make the page scroll several lines at a time, to allow javascript to be executed whilst scrolling in iOS. However i would like it to stop when it reaches a certain point in the page. I cant figure out why this is'nt working...

```
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById( 'pause').addEventListener( "click" , function(){
    if( window.scrollTimerId ){
        window.clearInterval(window.scrollTimerId );
        window.scrollTimerId = null
    }
    else{
    doScroll();
     window.scrollTimerId= window.setInterval( doScroll , 5);
    }

});


 var pauseTop = $pause.offset().top;

 function doScroll(){
         if (pauseTop >= 300 && pauseTop < 3004 || pauseTop >= 4000 && pauseTop < 4004 || pauseTop >= 7500 && pauseTop < 7504) {
         }else{
     window.scrollBy(0,15);
     }
}
}//]]>
```

As you can see this should only scroll if the view port is between 3000 & 3004, 400 & 4004 ect...

any ideas?

Comment: Bracketing..! `if ( (pauseTop>=300 && pauseTop<3004) || ( ...`

Comment: still nothing, wont scroll

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3btFN/

Comment: `#pause` is has a fixed position with it's `top` set to zero. Therefore your conditions would never be hit anyway...

Comment: how can i get the value of viewport to top?

Comment: See the answer I have posted... `$(window).scrollTop();` in JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `pauseTop` doesn't get recalculated. Include the calculation in `doScroll`.

Comment: still nothing, wont scroll

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so how about this:

### JQuery

```
$('#pause').click(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (y < 300) {
        scrollify(300);
    }
    else if (y < 3004) {
        scrollify(3004);
    }
    // etc...
});

function scrollify(y) {
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: y});
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3btFN/1/

This will scroll the window to a specified point, based on matching criteria.

Comment: This wont work as i need it to scroll only a few lines at a time to prevent iOS from preventing javascript being executed...

Comment: @user1949366 come again? I don't think your requirements are clear enough as I am now very lost...

Comment: if you read the first few sentances of my question, i said that i need the page to be moved only a few lines before being repeated. This is the only way of getting an iOS device to execute javascript whilst the document is being scrolled. Whilst navigating a page, usually, all animations, javascript, gifs are paused, until the document is static.

Comment: To clarify: you want a function(s) to be executed DURING scrolling, however iOS doesn't allow for this behaviour. Therefore it sounds like you are trying to run an event on a timer that checks the current position of the document to determine whether or not to execute your function(s). Right? I note that you're only allowing these functions to execute when the window top is within a very specific and *small* 5px measurement. If iOS pauses JS whilst scrolling are you sure your `setInterval` stuff is not going to be paused also? I have an idea... back soon...

Comment: correct. i have run a few tests and set interval is paused if the user manually scrolls but when it is static again, it resumes with no problems. thanks

Comment: So these functions(s) are **only** going to execute when the user happens to finish scrolling in a 5px region?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37054/discussion-between-gvee-and-user1949366)